# Iterating over a JSON is bringing the last result only

Tags: arrays, json, node.js, rss, iteration

I created an alert in Google Alerts and need to parse the XML. I'm using [`feed-reader`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/feed-reader) module and my code is the following:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  parse(url).then((rss) => {
    let title,
        link,
        publishedDate,
        contentSnippet = '';
    let json = {};

    rss['entries'].forEach((item) => {
      title = item.title;
      link = item.link.substring(42, item.link.indexOf('&ct='));
      publishedDate = item.publishedDate;
      contentSnippet = item.contentSnippet;
    });

    json = {
      title,
      link,
      publishedDate,
      contentSnippet
    };

    res.send(beautify(json, null, 2, 100));
  }).catch((err) => {
    res.send(err);
  });
});
```

I want to loop over what's inside the `"entries"` key. Although it works, the result is only the last.

Also, if I move `json` variable to inside the loop, the returned result is `[object Object]`, although with the right length.

I tried `JSON.stringify`, no difference.

Comment: console.log json object before res.send and paste it here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This expression assign the last entrie's value to the variables:

```
rss['entries'].forEach((item) => {
  title = item.title;
  link = item.link.substring(42, item.link.indexOf('&ct='));
  publishedDate = item.publishedDate;
  contentSnippet = item.contentSnippet;
});
```

Then you create the `json` from the last values.

Instead `Array#map` the entries into a new array. Each iteration should return an object.

```
const arr = rss['entries'].map(({ title, link, publishedDate, contentSnippet }) => ({
  title,
  link: link.substring(42, link.indexOf('&ct=')),
  publishedDate,
  contentSnippet
}));
```